# Need code for batch apex

Tags: apex, batch

I have 3 object study, member(contact) and study member ..where study member is the child of study and member. I have a requirement that i need a batch job to delete all shared record(study share) on daily basis based on a criteria(end date < today) as well as I have to update the member name with whom record is currently shared... suppose s1 study has 4 members a,b,c,d ..now a,d criteria has fulfilled so it will show only b,c in some fields(i.e. replacing by b,c instead of a,b,c,d) ..My code is as follows: getting a id duplicate error.. I'm trying to use map..need help to write down the code :

```
/*
An apex class to restrict edit access to check study
record for those members whose allocation is over
*/
global class Study_Revoke_sharing_upd implements  Database.Batchable<SObject>{ 
    global final String Query; 
    public datetime today = system.now();
    Public string status;
    global Study_Revoke_sharing_upd (){ 
        // get the records of Team member whose allocation is over
        Query= 'select RowCause,id,UserOrGroupId,parentid,AccessLevel from Study_ddc__Share where RowCause = \'Team_Member_Access_ddc__c\''; 
    }     
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
        return Database.getQueryLocator(Query); 
    } 

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Study_ddc__Share> Studyshare){ 
        // List<Study_ddc__c> st = new List<Study_ddc__c>([select id,name,Is_my_study_ddc__c from Study_ddc__c where Is_my_study_ddc__c !=null ]);

        List<Team_Member_ddc__c> TM = new List<Team_Member_ddc__c> ([select id,Study_ddc__c,Allocation_End_Date_ddc__c,study_ddc__r.Is_my_study_ddc__c,Member_ddc__c,
                                                                     Member_ddc__r.Amgen_ID_ddc__c,Member_ddc__r.OwnerID from Team_Member_ddc__c where Allocation_Status_ddc__c='Confirmed']);

        List <Study_ddc__Share> Lst_Std_shr = new List <Study_ddc__Share>();

        List <Study_ddc__c> study = new List <Study_ddc__c>();
          Map <id,study_ddc__c> mystudy = new  Map <id,study_ddc__c>();
        Map <id,study_ddc__c> mstudy = new  Map <id,study_ddc__c>([select id, Is_my_study_ddc__c from Study_ddc__c where Is_my_study_ddc__c !=null]); 
        // Check whether shared object record matched with study member record and already have access 
        for (Study_ddc__Share P : Studyshare)
        {
            status='N';
            for (Team_Member_ddc__c L : TM)
            {

              if(L.Study_ddc__c == P.parentid && L.Member_ddc__r.OwnerID==P.UserOrGroupID )//&& P.RowCause =='Team_Member_Access_ddc__c' )
                    {
                           status='Y';
                     if(L.Allocation_End_Date_ddc__c < today)

                        Lst_Std_shr.add(P);

                        //if( L.study_ddc__r.Is_my_study_ddc__c.Contains( L.Member_ddc__r.Amgen_ID_ddc__c) ==true)
                        if(mstudy.containsKey(L.Study_ddc__c)==true)
                        {
                            Study_ddc__c tstudy = new Study_ddc__c();
                            tstudy.Is_my_study_ddc__c=L.study_ddc__r.Is_my_study_ddc__c.replace(L.Member_ddc__r.Amgen_ID_ddc__c, '');
                            tstudy.Id= L.Study_ddc__c;    
                            mstudy.put(tstudy , tstudy.Id);
                        }

                        Study_ddc__c tstudy2 = new Study_ddc__c tstudy2 ();              
                        tstudy2.Is_my_study_ddc__c==mystudy.get(L.Study_ddc__c).Is_my_study_ddc__c;
                        mystudy.put(tstudy2, tstudy2Id)
                    }
                }
                 if(status=='N')
                    Lst_Std_shr.add(P);                 
            }

        if(Lst_Std_shr.size()>0)
            delete Lst_Std_shr;        
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception means that the list of records to delete contains the same record more than once. There are two places where I see `Lst_Std_shr.add(P);`

A quick way to prevent the same record from being added twice is to use a map. Try this:

```
global class Study_Revoke_sharing_upd implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    global final String Query;
    public datetime today = system.now();
    Public string status;
    global Study_Revoke_sharing_upd()
    {
        // get the records of Team member whose allocation is over
        Query= 'select RowCause,id,UserOrGroupId,parentid,AccessLevel from Study_ddc__Share where RowCause = \'Team_Member_Access_ddc__c\'';
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    { 
        return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Study_ddc__Share> Studyshare)
    { 
        // List<Study_ddc__c> st = new List<Study_ddc__c>([select id,name,Is_my_study_ddc__c from Study_ddc__c where Is_my_study_ddc__c !=null ]);

        List<Team_Member_ddc__c> TM = new List<Team_Member_ddc__c> ([select id,Study_ddc__c,Allocation_End_Date_ddc__c,study_ddc__r.Is_my_study_ddc__c,Member_ddc__c,
                                                                     Member_ddc__r.Amgen_ID_ddc__c,Member_ddc__r.OwnerID from Team_Member_ddc__c where Allocation_Status_ddc__c='Confirmed']);

        Map<Id, Study_ddc__Share> Map_Std_shr = new Map<Id, Study_ddc__Share>();

        List <Study_ddc__c> study = new List <Study_ddc__c>();
        Map <id,study_ddc__c> mystudy = new  Map <id,study_ddc__c>();
        Map <id,study_ddc__c> mstudy = new  Map <id,study_ddc__c>([select id, Is_my_study_ddc__c from Study_ddc__c where Is_my_study_ddc__c !=null]); 

        // Check whether shared object record matched with study member record and already have access 
        for (Study_ddc__Share P : Studyshare)
        {
            status='N';
            for (Team_Member_ddc__c L : TM)
            {

                if(L.Study_ddc__c == P.parentid && L.Member_ddc__r.OwnerID==P.UserOrGroupID )//&& P.RowCause =='Team_Member_Access_ddc__c' 
                {
                    status='Y';

                    if(L.Allocation_End_Date_ddc__c < today)
                    {
                        Map_Std_shr.put(P.Id, P);
                    }

                    //if( L.study_ddc__r.Is_my_study_ddc__c.Contains( L.Member_ddc__r.Amgen_ID_ddc__c) ==true)
                    if(mstudy.containsKey(L.Study_ddc__c)==true)
                    {
                        Study_ddc__c tstudy = new Study_ddc__c();
                        tstudy.Is_my_study_ddc__c=L.study_ddc__r.Is_my_study_ddc__c.replace(L.Member_ddc__r.Amgen_ID_ddc__c, '');
                        tstudy.Id= L.Study_ddc__c;    
                        mstudy.put(tstudy , tstudy.Id);
                    }

                    Study_ddc__c tstudy2 = new Study_ddc__c tstudy2 ();              
                    tstudy2.Is_my_study_ddc__c==mystudy.get(L.Study_ddc__c).Is_my_study_ddc__c;
                    mystudy.put(tstudy2, tstudy2Id)
                }
            }

            if(status=='N')
            {
                Map_Std_shr.put(P.Id, P);
            }
        }

        if(!Map_Std_shr.isEmpty())
        {
            delete Map_Std_shr.values();        
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}            
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the duplicate error for study record , not study share. I need map operation in study , but as im new to apex facing difficulty with syntax.

Comment: There's nothing else in your code beside the thing I mentioned that would give you a duplicate Id error. You do declare a List called "study", but you don't reference it anywhere in the class, so there's no way it'd have an error.